# protocol fault (couldn't read status): Undefined error: 0

Tags: android, adb

Having an issue with connecting to adb, I keep getting "protocol fault (couldn't read status): Undefined error: 0" when trying to run `adb devices`

What I have already tried:

- `adb kill-server` then `adb start-server`
- Killed the port in question manually from command line and activity monitor
- Restarted my computer and ran it as the first command off a fresh restart
- Checked and updated to latest versions in android studio
- Uninstalled and reinstalled from android studio
- Installed a new version of adb from homebrew

None of the above have solved the issue for me.

I ran `export ADB_TRACE=all` and then `adb devices` and am seeing the following trace come back

```
adb D 08-06 11:56:09 30020 148574 adb_trace.cpp:192] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
adb D 08-06 11:56:09 30020 148574 adb_trace.cpp:192] Version 29.0.1-5644136
adb D 08-06 11:56:09 30020 148574 adb_trace.cpp:192] Installed as /usr/local/bin/adb
adb D 08-06 11:56:09 30020 148574 adb_trace.cpp:192]
adb D 08-06 11:56:09 30020 148574 adb_client.cpp:153] _adb_connect: host:version
adb D 08-06 11:56:09 30020 148574 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=3 len=16 30303063686f73743a76657273696f6e 000chost:version
adb D 08-06 11:56:09 30020 148574 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=3 wanted=4
adb D 08-06 11:56:09 30020 148574 adb_io.cpp:91] readx: fd=3 disconnected
adb: failed to check server version: protocol fault (couldn't read status): Undefined error: 0
```

I'm unsure of what to try next but any suggestions would be appreciated

Update:
I'm using a 2018 Macbook Pro, other people I work with have the same issue, unsure if this is related but may help

Comment: do you have an antivirus? I had one and that was my problem

Comment: did you solve that issue?

Comment: The issue was resolved itself when I updated my version of macOS. I'm unsure if there was any antivirus issues in the background but as soon as soon as I moved onto Mojave it got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

1. check your network proxy macbook
2. allow RSA key fingerprint to allow USB debugging on your android device
   i'm also get that issue on my macbook, now adb conect is working

Comment: What does "check your network proxy macbook" mean to you?